# How to install a ROM with CWM when /data (and /sdcard) are encrypted and I can't reformat them?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, rom, unbricking

I used to run CyanogenMod 9.1 with device encryption on my Galaxy S3, and decided today that I wanted to try a CM 10 nightly.

A problem with device encryption that I didn't know about before is that it's impossible to turn off. ClockworkMod Recovery (5.8.4.3) can't mount the `/data` partition (and, by extension, `/sdcard`). This means that I can't use CWM to factory reset or install a new update.zip, since the update.zip must lie on the internal sdcard.

Trying "choose zip from sdcard" gives "E:Can't mount /sdcard/" and choosing "apply /sdcard/update.zip" gives "E:Can't mount /sdcard/update.zip". This happens even if I've used `adb` to put the update.zip in the `/sdcard` mountpoint.

Factory resetting from CWM gives these two errors: "Error mounting /data!" and "Error mounting /sdcard/.android_secure!". Factory resetting from CM9 didn't work. I've since tried to flash CM10 with MobileOdin, which didn't work, and now I can only boot to CWM.

Does anyone have any idea about how I could mount `/data` or otherwise get a working ROM?

I've taken backups of everything. The tools I suppose could help me, but I haven't tried because I'm new at this and don't want to hard-brick my phone, are fastboot and heimdall.

TL;DR: S3 only boots to CWM, but CWM won't mount `/data` and so can't flash zips.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed mine right now. Using Odin, load the original image of your phone from the exact provider in pda. *Now, it's like brand new.*

P.S. You have to unrar the image file, or Odin won't see it. After you unrar, it should have a MD5 file.

Comment: Thanks! I've never used Odin. Looks like a Windows program? I don't have access to a Windows computer =/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reboot to the bootloader? You can do so using `adb reboot bootloader`. From there, you can flash `boot.img` and `system.img`. Look at fastboot options.